# How to queue mail to send?

Tags: mu4e

What I like about my mbsync/mu4e setup is that I can download all my email and then read it all and respond to it all offline. But this doesn't work for sending mail, since if I'm offline, it won't let me send a message. How do you configure mu4e so that if you're offline, it puts your message in an outbox, and then sends it as soon as it gets a connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [mu4e manual node on queuing mail](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Queuing-mail.html) explains how to do this.  Quoting the manual:

> If you cannot send mail right now, for example because you are currently 
>   offline, you can queue the mail, and send it when you have restored your 
>   internet connection. You can control this from the Main view.
>
> To allow for queuing, you need to tell smtpmail where you want to store 
>   the queued messages. For example:
>
> ```
> (setq smtpmail-queue-mail t  ;; start in queuing mode
>
>       smtpmail-queue-dir   "~/Maildir/queue/cur")
> ```
>
> For convenience, we put the queue directory somewhere in our normal 
>   maildir. If you want to use queued mail, you should create this directory > before starting mu4e. The mu mkdir command may be useful here, so for 
>   example:
>
> `$ mu mkdir ~/Maildir/queue`
>
> `$ touch ~/Maildir/queue/.noindex`
>
> The file created by the touch command tells mu to ignore this directory 
>   for indexing, which makes sense since it contains smtpmail meta-data 
>   rather than normal messages; see the mu-mkdir and mu-index man-pages for 
>   details.
>
> Warning: when you switch on queued-mode, your messages won’t reach their  > destination until you switch it off again; so, be careful not to do this 
>   accidentally!

Comment: So, it'd be a matter of writing something to check whether emacs was connected to the Internet, and if it wasn't, turning on this variable? And then turning it off once it was connected again? Do you know how that would work?

Comment: @Jon : sorry, I don’t know how to do that. I’d like to know, though, so please post an answer if you figure it out.

Comment: Is there a way to view your queued emails in mu4e like any other mailbox?

Comment: @AstroFloyd it doesn't seem to allow that, I think because mu isn't indexing that folder.

Comment: @Johan I must have been asleep back then - I guess `rm ~/Maildir/queue/.noindex` would help (or not issuing `touch`).  I forgot to send my queued mail a few times, hence the question, but now I have a cron job that creates a pop-up every hour if I have queued emails (to help my sloppy memory).